# How to remove username field and password2 field from RegisterSerializer in django rest framework?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, authorization

When I call the api/seller/register api, the fields appear are username, password1 and password2. I want these removed and only want simple password, email and phone_num.

How to remove this?

I am trying to make a seller registration using RegisterSerializer. I tried with ModelSerailzers and provided fields as I want but this will lead to me the error saying save() only takes 1 argument.So, I just want these unnecessary fields removed using RegisterSerializer.

[image]

My model:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager with email as the unique identifier
    """

    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create user with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The email must be set")
        first_name = first_name.capitalize()
        last_name = last_name.capitalize()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(
            first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True.")
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")
        return self.create_user(first_name, last_name, email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="First name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Last name")
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True) 
    is_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

My serializer:

```
class SellerRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    seller = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True,)
    # username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    phone_num = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    # class Meta:
    #     model = User
    #     fields = ['seller','email', 'phone_num', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password']


    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        data = super(SellerRegisterSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()
        extra_data = {
            'phone_num': self.validated_data.get('phone_num', ''),
        }
        data.update(extra_data)
        return data

    def save(self, request, **kwargs):
        user = super(SellerRegisterSerializer, self).save(request)
        # user = super().save(is_seller=True)
        user.is_seller = True
        user.save()
        seller = Seller(seller=user,
                        phone_num=self.cleaned_data.get('phone_num'))
        seller.save()
        return user
```

My view:

```
class SellerRegisterView(RegisterView):
    serializer_class = SellerRegisterSerializer
```

Comment: Use AbstractBaseUser Instead of AbstractUser to remove the username field. For password1 and password2, use ModelSerializer instead of RegisterSerializer. Check this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer. You will have to put more effort, as you are trying to do it your way other than what django provide by default. It will help you learn more. Good luck.

Comment: I tried with ModelSerailzers and provided fields as I want but this will lead to me the error saying save() only takes 1 argument.So, I had to switch to Registerserializer. Is there any other way?

Comment: There is only one way: Learn from scratch. As you are using available 3rd party service rest_auth, you do not know what's happening inside. So learn from scratch. One Resource: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html

Comment: Hello Vinnet, can you have a look at this?? I tried with modelserializers but got an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66025389/save-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given?noredirect=1#comment116736233_66025389